# Save Scope Graphic of Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, graphics, simulink

I'm using simulink of Matlab R2012b. When I finish generating my model, I want to save the graphics obtained from it that are seen in the scope, but I can't find an easy way to do this. Does exist a way to save the graphics that I'm obtaining from the model that are seen in the scope?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find it so I asked.

Comment: Don't worry, it is not a crime ;)

Comment: Well, yes, but I like that idea of not repeating questions, so I have to respect that :P

Comment: You could vote to close your own question as duplicate, then it gets into the review queue and gets handled fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long way to do this is, before running the model, go to the terminal of matlab, and enter the next lines:

```
>>>shh = get(0,'ShowHiddenHandles');
>>>set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','On')
>>>set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
>>>set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off')
>>>saveas(gcf,'mypic.jpg')
>>>set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles',shh)
```

And the file will be saved in the current folder where you are working.

The other way is doing a screenshot, and then pasting it on a program like paint or inkscape.

Comment: You could also save the data to the workspace and then use standard MATLAB `plot` commands. It won't look like a Simulink scope, but like a MATLAB figure, but it will be the same data.